# Menu items float left and down

Tags: css, css-float

I am creating a menu using an unordered list that mixes list items of different sizes, some are half the height and width of others.  They all float left.  What I'm getting is this:
[image: menu with float left]

If I add clear:left to the third small item I get this:
[image: menu with clear left]

What I want is for the second and fourth (or third and forth) small items to float below the other two, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with css?  The menu is created dynamically so forcing a particular position won't work, it needs to be able to flow into the proper position.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would having multiple `<ul/>` work for you ? If so, the following Codepen would work : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPaVar

Same code as an embedded code snippet :

```css
ul {
  list-style : none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}

li {
  margin: 0
}

li.left {
  float: left
}

div.small {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px
}

div.large {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="left">
    <div class="large">A</div>
  </li>
  <li class="left">
    <ul>
      <li class="left">
        <div class="small">1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="left">
        <div class="small">2</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="left">
        <div class="small">3</div>
      </li>
      <li class="left">
        <div class="small">4</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left">
    <div class="large">B</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `grid-auto-flow: dense`
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.main li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inner-div li {
  width: 99px;
  height: 89px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.inner-div {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="main">
    <li>div 1</li>
    <li>div 2
      <ul class="inner-div">
        <li>div 21</li>
        <li>div 21</li>
        <li>div 21</li>
        <li>div 21</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>div 3</li>


  </ul>
</div>
```